# Difference of two columns in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xlwings

Hi I tring to get two columns from Excel and parse to a DataFrame, after that I need subtract this columns.

This is my code

```
ndf = xw.Range('AI1:AJ' + str(len(last_row))).options(pd.DataFrame).value

#Error in this line below
ndf['VC-BC'] = ndf['VC'] - ndf['BC']

#xw.Range("BH1").options(index=False).value = ndf

print(ndf.head(20))
```

Cross post in :
https://python-forum.io/Thread-Difference-of-two-columns-in-Pandas-dataframe

Comment: By `subtract`, do you mean to remove rows that appear in both columns `VC` and `BC`?

Comment: imagine line 1, 2, 3, 4 then look at header Result
Header -  VC | BC | Result
1           -  10 | 15   | 5
2           -  05 | 5     | 0
3           -  07 | 06   | 1
4           -  10 | 4     | 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggestion to make it work is to add condition `index=False` to `options` function.

`ndf = xw.Range('AI1:AJ' + str(len(last_row))).options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value`

`xw` has parsed your column `VC` as index, which caused `KeyError` when you try to operate on that column.